# How can I prevent tar from creating an empty archive?

Tags: ksh, tar

```
/tmp/-> ls ab*
/tmp/-> ls: ab*: No such file or directory

/tmp/-> tar -cvf ab.tar abc*
tar: abc*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
/tmp/->
/tmp/-> ls ab*
ab.tar
/tmp/-> tar -tvf ab.tar
/tmp/->
```

As can be seen there are no files matching pattern abc*, however output file named ab.tar got created with no content. Is there a switch/option than can be passed to tar command so that no output file is created when there are no input file?

Comment: Why not check to see if there are any files to archive in the first place?

Comment: Are you aware that the tar program actually *is* called with the file name `abc*` (the unexpanded wildcard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m fond of using a `for`-as-`if` construct for such cases:

```
for x in abc*; do
    # exit the loop if no file matching abc* exists
    test -e "$x" || break
    # by now we know at least one exists (first loop iteration)
    tar -cvf ab.tar abc*
    # and since we now did the deed already… exit the “loop”
    break
done
```

The body of the “loop” is run through exactly once, but the shell does the globbing for us. (I normally use `continue` in the place of the first `break`, but that’s probably not needed.)

Alternatively, you can use the shell to expand the glob into `$*`…

```
set -- abc*
test -e "$1" && tar -cvf ab.tar abc*
```

If your script runs under `set -e`, use `if test …; then tar …; fi` instead, otherwise it will abort when no file exists.

All these variants work in plain [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) as well.

Comment: This would work with a single `break` as well:
`for x in abc*; do
    test -e "$x" && tar -cvf ab.tar abc*; 
    break; 
done`

Comment: In the `set -e` case, it's sufficient to append `|| :` to prevent the error exit.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld it would, but that would *also* prevent catching errors from `tar`, which is why one runs under `set -e` in the first place, so I chose to not advice that. Also, the commented example is deliberately verbose.

Comment: What about `! test -e "$1" || tar -cvf ab.tar abc*` ? That would also circumvent the error exit on `test -e` while keeping it for `tar ...`

Comment: I think your solution is easier to read when you move the for-loop without the tar to a function returning true/false and use it with `testfiles abc* && tar -cvf ab.tar.abc*`.

Comment: I thank you both for the simplifications I could have done myself; however, this is a training tool, and as such, backgrounds should be explained. Furthermore, it’s not as simple in all cases, and nesting and/or constructs, `if`, etc. can get nasty to read. The way I wrote the first example is universally reusable. – @HenkLangeveld some shells choke on the `!` (including some versions of GNU bash) so I don’t use it in portable code.

Comment: @mirabilos After all, I like your *pure shell* solution, in that it does not depend on external command as mine does.  Not enough people appreciate the power of the bare shell.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a switch/option than can be passed to tar command so that no output file is created when there are no input file?

**Gnu tar does not have such an option**.

Here are two alternatives.  You need to study them and figure out what would work for you, as they're a bit of a hack.

You could do something like:

*Tar, test, remove when empty*

```
tar -cvf ab.tar abc* ||
    tar tf ab.tar | read ||
        rm ab.tar
```

Explanation:

If `tar -cvf ...` fails, get the contents with `tar tf ...`.

If the `read` fails, the archive was empty, and it's save to remove it.

---

Or you could try:

*Test, then tar*

```
ls abc* | read && tar -cvf ab.tar abc*
```

This would not create the empty tar file in the first place.

Comment: No, you **do not parse ls output**. Also, creating the file then removing it is… weird. And this can hide other errors (e.g. genuine archive creation errors).

Comment: @mirabilos There are good reasons not to parse the output of the `ls` utility, because it's not an api, and its output is not very predictable between unix/linux distros.
Nevertheless, this code does *not parse* `ls` output. The code does not care what `ls` produces, only that it does, or does not.  I don't think there is any alternative simpler than this.

Comment: @mirabilos Interesting things indeed.  Using `\ls ` would prevent that, and we already need to add a `2> /dev/null` to clean up the hack a bit.   Thanks for mksh btw, nice POSIX shell you've got there.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to get the shell to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# safetar -- execute tar safely

sh -O failglob -c 'tar cvf ab.tar abc*'
```

Comment: `sh: sh: -O: unknown option` – but even with `-o`, this won’t work: `sh: failglob: bad option` – if you use bash/dash/ksh93/mksh/yash/zsh/…-specific features, *absolutely* **do not** use `/bin/sh` in the shebang.

Comment: @mirabilos It was tested and it works [and /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash].  And /bin/sh was merely for illustration.  Sheesh!

Comment: `/bin/sh` is **not** a symlink to `bash`, and the question is explicitly for [tag:ksh]. Also, this is by no means a feature of POSIX sh.

Comment: @mirabilos The question was about tar.  I can find no reference to ksh in OP's post.  And, sh _is_ a symlink on Linux.  And, you can do: `#!/bin/csh` `tar cvf ab.tar abc*` as well

Comment: The question was about tar called from ksh. The question is *tagged* ksh. The question does not mention Linux. `/bin/sh` may be a copy or hardlink, not a symlink, on Linux. `/bin/sh` may be a bash, ash, dash, or even mksh on Linux. So, stop inventing excuses, your answer is way off.